# Oracle DB SQL - check if at least one dataset exists for each month

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a large table where a full tablescan on my server takes around 2 minutes (150 mio datasets).

The table holds sales transactions for respective days of the year. It is indexed by date.

I am looking for an efficient way to get the info for each month if at least one dataset  is present in the month.

Normally I would do:

```
select month, count(*)
from transaction_table
group by month
```

This takes too long.

The query does not need to count every dataset in each month, it just needs to look if at least one dataset is present for each month.

Is there a more performant way to do this in a single query?

Comment: Are the indexed columns set to `NOT NULL`?  If not, that would prevent the optimizer from using an index full scan.  Although I would still expect Gordon's second query to be the fastest solution.  If you post the DDL for your table and an explain plan of the queries then someone can probably figure out what's
going on.

Answer (score 4):

If it is indexed by date, then the following should be pretty fast:

```
select distinct year(date), month(date)
from transaction_table tt;
```

Otherwise, you could create a list of months of interest and then do the comparison in the `where` clause:

```
select months.*
from (select to_date('2013-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as firstday, to_date('2013-01-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as lastday from dual union all
      select to_date('2013-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as firstday, to_date('2013-02-28', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as lastday
     ) as months
where exists (select 1
              from transaction_table tt
              where tt.date between months.firstday and months.lastday
             )
```

Using `exists` should strongly suggest the use of the index to the optimizer.

Comment: I tried "select distinct month" and surprisingly it did not improve much. Maybe 10% increase.

Comment: I also tried out the method using the "exists". Unfortunately no performance increase for me. Actually it took 5x the time as the original statement.

Comment: @caliph . . . Wow.  That's interesting.  I would expect it to be the cost of a handful of index lookups.  Are you sure you have an index on the right column?

Comment: ...I was thinking about this as well. Actually the issue must be in the index. I have an index "shop,date,status_flag". And I have in my where clause "shop=123 and status=1". So date is the only variable here. To my knowledge the index is usable for date here.

Comment: Hmmm, you should probably ask another question with more detail about the table and how you are accessing it.  Changing your question now will render the existing answers suspect, but the additional information is quite important.

Answer (score 0):

you might try to get a single value from the index - this will depend on the explain plan - but something similar to this maybe:

```
select distinct ( month ) from transaction_table
```

an alternate would be to preserve the months in a separate table with a trigger - this denormalization would greatly speed up you query.

Comment: I tried "select distinct month" and surprisingly it did not improve much. Maybe 10% increase.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is just to look if at least one dataset is present for each month.

then why cant we try this,

```
select month
from transaction_table
group by month
HAVING COUNT(1) > 0
```

Comment: just gave this a try. Unfortunately same performance as the original statement.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest getting a list of distinct dates and then get the list of distinct months from that.

```
SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(A.DATES) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DATE AS DATES FROM TRANSACTION_TABLE) A
```

The inner query will use the index on DATE and as long as it is a date field and not datetime it will return only 365 single column rows per year in the data. The outer query will make short work of converting that into the desired list of months.